# Autopopulate a column utilizing the MATCH function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have 2 workbooks: "MainWorkbook.xlsm" and "ReferenceWorkbook.xlsx". The reference workbook is a report that the main workbook pulls data from.

There is a column in my main workbook called "Vendor Name", which is column J. The column in the reference workbook that "Vendor Name" would be referencing is column X, named "Vendor_Data". Both of the vendor columns in the 2 worksheets are non-numeric data types. Furthermore, both of these worksheets are subject to variations in row counts; I may have 200 rows in "Mainworkbook.xlsm" one day and 230 the next. The same applies for "ReferenceWorkbook". The vendor column in "MainWorkbook.xlsm" will remain static as far as it's index value goes, but the position of the vendor column in ReferenceWorkbook.xlsx could potentially change in the future (ex. going from column x to column y). The header row in "MainWorkbook") is row 2, while the header row in "ReferenceWorkbook" is row 1.

What I would like to do is build a macro that will automatically populate my vendor column in "MainWorkbook" by first matching to the vendor column in "ReferenceWorkbook" based on their headers and then matching rows by their primary keys (Column C in "MainWorkbook" and column K in "ReferenceWorkbook"). The primary key column in "ReferenceWorkbook" is also subject to having it's column index changed, like it's vendor column, so I would like to do all of my header matching based on header names, not their index values.

Since I'm just starting out with VBA, the best I have so far is an incomplete and very logically flawed block of code:

Sub New_Macro()

```
Dim ran As Range, source_header As Range, target_header As Range
Dim source As Workbook, source_sheet As Worksheet, target As Workbook, target_sheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, Match_header As Integer

Set source = Application.Workbooks("ReferenceWorkbook.xlsx")
Set Reference_sheet = source.Worksheets("ReferenceSheet")
Set target = Application.Workbooks("MainWorkbook.xlsm")
Set target_sheet = target.Worksheets("MainSheet")
Set source_worksheet_header = source_sheet.Range("X1")
Set target_worksheet_header = target_sheet.Range("J2")

LR = target_sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
j = 10
Set ran = target_sheet.Range("J3" & LR)

ran.ClearContents

Do While j < 11

    For Each cell In target_worksheet_header
        For i = 3 To LR
            Match_header = source_worksheet_header.Find(cell.Value)
                    target_sheet.Cells(i, j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(source_sheet.Range("X"), WorksheetFunction.Match(target_sheet.Cells(i, 10).Value, source_sheet.Range("X"), LR), Match_header)
                    On Error Resume Next
        Next i
        j = j + 1
    Next cell

Loop

End Sub
```

Does anyone have a way to turn this into an actual solution? Any help would be wonderous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiled but not tested:

```
Sub New_Macro()

    Dim ran As Range, c As Range
    Dim source_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim target_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim srcVendorCol As Range, srcIdCol As Range, f As Range
    Dim vndr, r, id
    Dim LR As Long

    Set source_sheet = Workbooks("ReferenceWorkbook.xlsx") _
                           .Worksheets("ReferenceSheet")
    Set target_sheet = Workbooks("MainWorkbook.xlsm") _
                           .Worksheets("MainSheet")

    Set f = source_sheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="Vendor_Data", _
                           lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        Set srcVendorCol = f.EntireColumn
    End If

    Set f = Nothing
    Set f = source_sheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="PrimaryKey", _
                           lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        Set srcIdCol = f.EntireColumn
    End If

    If srcVendorCol Is Nothing Or srcIdCol Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Required column headers not found in source sheet!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'find last populated cell in Col J
    LR = target_sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row 'EDIT
    Set ran = target_sheet.Range("J3:J" & LR)

    For Each c In ran.Cells

        id = c.EntireRow.Cells(3).Value

        If Len(id) > 0 Then 'EDIT - added check for Id length 

            r = Application.Match(id, srcIdCol, 0)

            If Not IsError(r) Then
                c.Value = Application.Index(srcVendorCol, r, 1)
            Else
                c.Value = "Id not found"
            End If

        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! It worked like a charm.. Just one thing though. When I add in new columns to my main worksheet and run the macro, it only fills the rows previous to the ones I added in. I can't see why it would have anything to do with your code since there was nothing in it that designated a strict number of columns. I have primary keys for all of the new rows and the reference workbook contains those primary keys and they have vendors assigned to them.. Do you know off the top of your head what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Do you mean when you add new *rows* ?  It may be that those new rows had no value in ColA (which was being used to find the last row).  I edited my answer to get the `LR` value from Col J, so that should populate all rows which have something in that column.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. I editied my code like yours only I used column c which is the column that contains the primary keys and it worked!!! Thank you VERY much